# Set annotation value with xtend 2.7.3?

Tags: java, xtend

all 
I was migrating my project from xtend 2.4.3 to 2.7.3

I got some problems.
Here is the code works on 2.4.3

```
val AttrType = findTypeGlobally(typeof(Attr));
val fld = Cls.addField(Pkt::getMemberName(m)) 
[
    val annot = addAnnotation(AttrType )
    annot.set("value", GenHelper::getAnnot(m))
    visibility = Visibility::PUBLIC
]
setFieldType(m, fld, context)
```

On 2.7.3, addAnnotation returns AnnotationReference.

There is no way to set value into the AnnotationReference.
How to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `addAnnotation` method that takes a lambda to initialize the annotation reference. In that lambda, you have access to an `AnnotationReferenceBuildContext` to set values.

```
val AttrType = findTypeGlobally(typeof(Attr))
val fld = Cls.addField(Pkt::getMemberName(m)) 
[
    val annot = addAnnotation(AttrType) [
        set("value", GenHelper::getAnnot(m))
    ]
    visibility = Visibility::PUBLIC
]
...
```

Also note:

1. `typeOf`has become obsolete. You can use `Attr` directly to refer to the class.
2. `::` for static member access can be replaced by a simple `.` now.
3. If the class `Attr`is on the classpath of both, the active annotation project and the client project, you don't have to use `findTypeGlobally.
4. static (extension) imports could help you write even more concise code, e.g.

So your code could become

```
import static extension <whereever>.Pkt.*
import static extension <whereever>.GenHelper.*
import static org.xtend.lib.macro.declaration.Visibility.*
...

Cls.addField(m.memberName) [
    Attr.addAnnotation [
        'value'.set(m.annot)
    ]
    visibility = PUBLIC
    type = m.fieldType(context) // might need further refactoring
]
```

...